# Помогите исправить ошибку

Tags: javascript

Почему у меня все позиции уходят в минус тысячи? В чём у меня здесь ошибка? Я хотел, чтоб она возрашалась в обратно в начальную позицию.

```
var slaid = document.getElementById("slaid");
var init = 1, pos1 = 0, pos2 = 110, pos3 = 220, pos4 = 330, x = 110/200;
(function position() {
  var norm_pos = setInterval(function() {
    pos1 = pos1 - x;
    pos2 = pos2 - x;
    pos3 = pos3 - x;
    pos4 = pos4 - x;
    console.log(pos4);
    inner_pos = pos1 + " 0," + pos2 + " 0," + pos3 + " 0," + pos4 + " 0";
    slaid.style.backgroundPosition = inner_pos;
    if ((pos4 > 0 && pos4 < 1) || (pos4 > 110 && pos4 < 111) || (pos4 > 220 && pos4 < 221)) {
      clearInterval(norm_pos);
    }
  }, 10);
  console.warn(init);
  if (++init == 4) {
    pos1 = 0;
    pos2 = 110;
    pos3 = 220;
    pos4 = 330;
    slaid.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0, 110 0, 220 0, 330 0";
  }
  position();
})();
```

Comment: во первых вы криво вставили ссылку на картинку, во вторых, код надо вставлять в виде кода а не картинки !

Comment: удалите тогда чтоли предыдущий вопрос, раз отредактировать его не захотелось...